# Help Center: On/Off topic when refering to complete code solutions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope, help-center

While not all new users read the help center I am seeing many users asking something similar to the following:

> Hey,
>
> So im not good at code wrting and such. Can your create a script /
>   program that will do the following?
>
> 1. Get data from place
> 2. Convulted parseing of data
> 3. Ouput to Excel
>
> Thanks in advance!

Questions like this will get flagged and in most cases closed for a number of very good reasons.

My issue is that this behaviour does not appear to be explicitly discouraged in some parts of the Help Center.

1. In "What topics can I ask about here?" I see this line which technically covers it "have a bit of source code" but again that doesnt seem very explicit.
2. For "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" that scenario is not covered at all and i dont think it belongs there given the scope of the article.

I understand that we cannot cover every possible issue and that not everyone reads the help. That being said, this situation is seen rather frequently.

Could we add a section in the help under "Some questions are still off-topic..."

> x. Question requesting solutions created from scratch. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. The community is more than happy to help you if your code has an issue.

or some verbage to that effect?

Also, do new accounts have to read the Help Center? Or is it just recommended?

Perhaps reading the Help Center could be a prerequisite of creating a new account?

Comment: No one is ever required to read the help. You get a badge if you read the entire "tour" page though. And I think this is ok, but don't make it a close reason as well.

Comment: You are most likely right. Just spit balling ideas. Having that comment at the end might be directing my question somewhere else. Is there something in the help where we can say complete code solutions are off topic?

Comment: I have always thought that, "a specific programming problem," should cover us not writing an entire codez. Because a specific programming problem would be "why does `int two = 3;` result in `if (two == 2)` being `false`". Not, "How do I write an Android chat app. Full code solution would be appreciated. K. thx". But maybe you are right and it isn't explicit enough.

Comment: Well, there's a fine line to walk between on an off-topic question and an on-topic. *How do I convert an `int` to a `String` in Java* is on-topic, wheras *Plz make me a TXTING APP K thnx by* is not. Not saying this is a bad idea, just saying that the wording should show that. I'm not sure how you would word it though...

Comment: Maybe the description of `Too broad` should be expanded to include "or the answer would require writing large amounts of code from scratch, rather than correcting problems in the code in the question."

Comment: I should think that would be an easy to implement comprimise.

Comment: just found a a question that was asking for a complete program. could not find a way to correctly flag it.

Comment: @Moh-Aw I just use too broad. It is the closest thing and it makes the most sense out of the other flags.